# Display date as dd-mm-yyyy format for input type=date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

**I have my code :**

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="training_date" 
name="training_date" placeholder=" select" value="" 
onfocus="(this.type='date')" 
onfocusout="(this.type='date')" max=<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>>
```

I need to display my date in following date-format **dd-mm-yyyy** format in the `textbox`.

Comment: `type="date"` wont work for firefox and IE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v1pxxsj1/ see this

Comment: Use https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ It has support to multiple browsers and you can format date as per your requirement..

Comment: The whole point of `type="date"` is to display the browsers HTML-5 datepicker (Chrome and Edge only) which displays the date in the users culture, not yours

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/2702249

Comment: Basically, you want to pick date from datepicker and then display in dd-mm-yyyy format in another `textbox` ?

Comment: no display in the same textbox

Comment: @HariPriya: Displaying in same textbox which is actually `datepicker` is not possible. Because that's the entry point for date input. 
I have answered my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

What I would recommend is to make a array with the 12 months of the year (because the will never change)

```
_currentDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    for (var i = 0; this.months.length > i; i++) {
      if (date.getMonth() === i) {
        var displayMonth = this.months[i].month;
      }
    }
    var displayDate = date.getDate() + ' ' + displayMonth + ' ' + date.getFullYear();
    return displayDate;
  }
```

Use the value that you return in your function you just need to insert where you want to display it so in your case your input

Hope this helps :)

Comment: nothing worked someone help me waiting for your valuable reply

Answer (score 1):

Please note: `<input type="date">` is not supported in IE and Firefox. Hence, it's not good idea to implement it in as it's against robust UI/UX design, and might invite later bugs. 
You should use jquery's datepicker, moment.js or combination of both to achieve your requirement.

To close the question and provide what can be done and tested. Here is implementation.

In this example:

- I am assigning today's date to `<input type="date">` by forming a date string in `yyyy-mm-dd` format and setting attribute `value`
- whenever I am changing the the date in `#datepicker`, I am forming a date string in dd-mm-yyyy format and providing it as value to `#textbox`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var d = new Date();      
        
   function twoDigitDate(d){
      return ((d.getDate()).toString().length == 1) ? "0"+(d.getDate()).toString() : (d.getDate()).toString();
    };
        
    function twoDigitMonth(d){
      return ((d.getMonth()+1).toString().length == 1) ? "0"+(d.getMonth()+1).toString() : (d.getMonth()+1).toString();
    };    
      
    var today_ISO_date = d.getFullYear()+"-"+twoDigitMonth(d)+"-"+twoDigitDate(d); // in yyyy-mm-dd format
        
    document.getElementById('datepicker').setAttribute("value", today_ISO_date);
       
     var dd_mm_yyyy;
     $("#datepicker").change( function(){
        changedDate = $(this).val(); //in yyyy-mm-dd format obtained from datepicker
        var date = new Date(changedDate);
        dd_mm_yyyy = twoDigitDate(date)+"-"+twoDigitMonth(date)+"-"+date.getFullYear(); // in dd-mm-yyyy format
        $('#textbox').val(dd_mm_yyyy);
        //console.log($(this).val());
        //console.log("Date picker clicked");
        });
        
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 50%;height:50px; float:left;">
  Enter your Birthday!!:<br>
  <input id="datepicker" type="date" name="bday" style="margin-bottom: 200px;"></br><br>
  </div>

  <div style="width: 50%;height:50px; float:right;">
  Date chosen(dd-mm-yyyy):<br>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" value="dd-mm-yyyy"></input>
  </div>
</br></br></br></br></br></br>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> type="date" is not supported in Firefox, or Internet Explorer 11 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `input type="date"` is supported since Firefox 57 (released in November 2017).

Answer (score -3):

You can use the below code to achieve this.

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="training_date" name="training_date" placeholder=" select" value="" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='date')" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" >
```